# Is it possible to capture a variable number of parameters in a lambda?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda

Consider the following set of examples.

1. The function `takeOnlyVoidFunction` takes a function with zero arguments and simply executes it.
2. The function `takeVariableArguments` takes a variable number of arguments and executes the function using the arguments.
3. The function `captureVariableArgs` attempts to convert the second function into a lambda form that is acceptable by the first function, but it does not compile.

**How can I make the function `captureVariableArgs` compile and exhibit the correct behavior of converting a function with a variable number of arguments into a closure with no arguments?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

void takeOnlyVoidFunction(std::function<void()> task) {
    task();
}

template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
    void takeVariableArguments(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args) {
     __f(__args...);
}

// How can I make this function compile?
template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
    void captureVariableArgs(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args) {
    takeOnlyVoidFunction([=]() { __f(__args...);});
}

void normalFunction(int a, int b) {
    printf("I am a normal function which takes params (%d,%d)\n", a, b);
}

int main() {
    int a = 7;
    int b = 8;
    takeVariableArguments(normalFunction, a, b);
    takeOnlyVoidFunction([=](){ normalFunction(a,b);});
    captureVariableArgs(normalFunction, a, b);
}
```

I'm running `gcc 4.9.2`. Here is the compiler error I see.

```
g++ -std=c++11    Test.cc   -o Test
Test.cc: In instantiation of ‘captureVariableArgs(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)::<lambda()> [with _Callable = void (&)(int, int); _Args = {int&, int&}]’:
Test.cc:16:38:   required from ‘struct captureVariableArgs(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(int, int); _Args = {int&, int&}]::<lambda()>’
Test.cc:16:50:   required from ‘void captureVariableArgs(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(int, int); _Args = {int&, int&}]’
Test.cc:28:45:   required from here
Test.cc:16:34: error: variable ‘__f’ has function type
     takeOnlyVoidFunction([=]() { __f(__args...);});
                                  ^
Test.cc:16:34: error: variable ‘__f’ has function type
Test.cc: In instantiation of ‘struct captureVariableArgs(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(int, int); _Args = {int&, int&}]::<lambda()>’:
Test.cc:16:50:   required from ‘void captureVariableArgs(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(int, int); _Args = {int&, int&}]’
Test.cc:28:45:   required from here
Test.cc:16:34: error: field ‘captureVariableArgs(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(int, int); _Args = {int&, int&}]::<lambda()>::<__f capture>’ invalidly declared function type
In file included from Test.cc:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:2418:7: error: ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor) [with _Functor = captureVariableArgs(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(int, int); _Args = {int&, int&}]::<lambda()>; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]’, declared using local type ‘captureVariableArgs(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(int, int); _Args = {int&, int&}]::<lambda()>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
       function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
       ^
```

---

**Update**: A more minimal example demonstrating this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// How can I make this function compile?
template<typename _Callable>
void captureVariableArgs(_Callable&& __f) {
    takeOnlyVoidFunction( [=]{ __f(); } );
}

void normalFunction() {
    printf("I am a normal function\n");
}

int main(){
    captureVariableArgs(normalFunction);
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles and works, what is the problem you see?

Comment: The function with the comment on it doesn't compile for me.  Are you on clang or gcc?

Comment: Will update with compile errors in a couple minutes.

Comment: Well, the code as you posted it compiles on all the compilers I've tried. But if I add the call to `captureVariableArgs(normalFunction, a, b);` then all the gcc versions(up to the HEAD) fails to compile while clang and MSVC compiles it w/o any complains. So based on this fact and that I don't see why it would not compile I think it is a bug in gcc

Comment: @ixSci, Please see update to question, where I have added the function call to the breaking function, as well as the compiler error. Do you know of a workaround for `gcc` that would achieve the same effect?

Comment: You have several functions in your code that have a return type of `int` but don't return anything.

Comment: This can be further reduced: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/treXuVdO8sAClkLN

Comment: @dyp, I'm going to fix the return values, but I prefer the more explicit multiple functions so I can show the counterexamples that do work.

Comment: This is a gcc bug as far as I can tell; for the bug report, a minimal example is useful.

Comment: @dyp, I have removed the extraneous return types and appended the minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another potential workaround for GCC, instead of using a lambda, you could use `std::bind`:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto captureVariable(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    return std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This works for me under GCC 4.9.3.

Comment: Actually, I did consider this as well and it compiled it ran but I wasn't sure whether it was equivalent. Is it semantically equivalent?

Comment: It's not quite semantically equivalent to your example, as you copy in the arguments when you use `[=]`; this should actually forward them.

Comment: @Yuushi, I believe `bind` will copy all its arguments. It has to store them so it can't just forward them.

Comment: @ixSci Forwarding them just means passing them along as rvalues or lvalues. `std::bind` can then move them if it gets rvalues.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the post compiles fine with the latest clang&MSVC compilers but all the gccs refuse to compile it. So it seems a bug in gcc. Nevertheless, I found a way to make gcc happy: just don't use an "universal reference" on the callable argument, like this:

```
template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
int captureVariableArgs(_Callable _f, _Args&&... _args) {
    return takeOnlyVoidFunction([=]() { _f(_args...);});
}
```

I can't explain why gcc doesn't accept your version, though. I'm not familiar with gcc-style error reporting and can't extract the true cause from the error message. But I think the workaround is ok since I don't see any value in "universal reference" in this case. In fact, I don't see why you use it on the args either.

Comment: I use universal reference because I'm implementing a threading library and `std::thread` implementation in gcc uses a universal reference for the arguments, and I'm guessing it does so for performance and flexibility.

Comment: Well it's copied anyway by the lambda with the `[=]`. Maybe you can move it somehow in the capture-list, thereby keeping still just one copy with movable types.

Comment: @merlin2011, in this function it makes no sense — you just copy it with the capture list

Comment: @Jarod42, it might end up in UB given some temp object provided as an argument.

Comment: The lambda is called directly, so no problem here. but indeed, if we just return the lambda, it would be problematic. Btw reference capture allows to work with move only objects.

Comment: When you don't use a reference for `_Callable`, then the argument will decay to a function pointer, and the outer `_f` (the function parameter) will also have type *pointer to function*. OTOH, if you use `_Callable&&`, then the outer `_f` has type *reference to function*. The inner `_f` should still have type *pointer to function*, but gcc seems to fail to decay it.

Comment: The other answer seems to work on a broader range of gcc's.

Comment: I was slightly incorrect in my previous comment: the inner `_f` should also be a reference if the outer `_f` is a reference. gcc seems to not implement this correctly.